# How to change multiple layers / frames duration at the same time in the Photoshop Video Timeline?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers, animation, video

I can hold and drag each individual layer on timeline to increase its duration but it's such a pain.

Is there a workaround to change (increase) all layers on timeline to have the same duration?

Answer (score 5):

This is a bit late, but...

You know how you can select multiple files by

1. Choosing the first file
2. Then holding down <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> key and
   choosing the last file
3. Which then automatically selects all the
   files inbetween (inclusively) ...

You can do something similar here.

1. Select the first frame you want
2. Hold down <kbd>Shift</kbd>
3. Then select the last frame you want.

This will select all the desired frames. All you have to do is then change the duration of one and it will apply to all selected.

===

For this to work, gotta be in "frame animation" mode vs. "timeline animation" mode

Comment: OP specifically mentioned timeline, not frames.

Answer (score 2):

You might be interested in [The Animator’s Toolbar](http://photoshopanimation.com/the_animators_toolbar/):

[image: @PS_Animation tweeted: Ever tried trimming multiple layers at once, with a single click?]

<sub>@PS_Animation tweeted: Ever tried trimming multiple layers at once, with a single click?</sub>

A new update (2.5) is also coming soon, which supports moving and trimming multiple layers, even inside Video Groups.

[image: animated demo]

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, changing the fps setting will change all layers' duration proportional to the length of the clip. I was working on an animation that was intended to be part of a set of small multiples. I wanted different instances to move more quickly than others, so rather than getting all tweaky I changed the frames per second on the ones I wanted to go really fast, and the ones I wanted to go really slow, and exported them. It worked for my purposes, but again, I'm not sure that's what you're asking.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Linda. I basically ask how to make all layers end at 20:00f instead of say 11:00f without having to manually adjust each layer's duration.

Comment: Drag your current time indicator to 20:00f, and select the layer. Then from the Timeline menu, select "Move Layer End Point To Current Time". You would have to do it on each layer, but it's more precise than dragging. http://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/editing-video-animation-layers-photoshop.html